# Static block + cannot find symbol

Tags: java

**Java 14**

```
public class Ex14 {
    static String strDef = "At the point of definition";

    static {String strBlock = "In a static block";}

    public static void main (String [] args){       
        System.out.println(Ex14.strDef);
        System.out.println(Ex14.strBlock);
    }

}
```

**Result**

$ javac Ex14.java

```
Ex14.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(Ex14.strBlock);
                               ^
  symbol:   variable strBlock
  location: class Ex14
1 error
```

**Could you help me understand why this error happens?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `strBlock` variable is a local variables within the static initializer block. Its scope is limited to that block, just like any other local variable. If you want to be able to access it in the `main` method, you'll need to declare it as a field:

```java
static strBlock; // Static field declaration

static {
    // Static field initialization
    strBlock = "Initialized in a static block";
}
```